# Improve performance for loading 3000+ records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, datatables

I've used knockout to bind my data coming from the server in a datatable. I use the below code to set the data in the script.

```csharp
var ServerData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
```

And bind it like this:

```
self.CompanyList = ko.observableArray(ServerData);
```

I've more than 3000 records and there comes the performance issue. I introduced caching on the server side but it didn't improve things.

How can I improve the performance of page? I feel the downside is on the client side. Can You give me any suggestions on improving the performance?

Comment: Why are you trying to load that many records in client side? Perhaps you should use some kind of paging and load less data at a time?

Comment: Do You mind telling me how to do that? I'm new to knockout.

Comment: What exactly are your performance problems? The mere creation of the observable array shouldn't be that much of an issue. Do you create a HTML list based on the contents of the array (e.g. using a 'foreach' binding)? Do you experience performance issue with scrolling this list (which can be a difficult problem to attack)?

Comment: @gzost The page itself loads really slow other than that everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to load many records at once rather you can use server side paging for better performance.
for paging with KO see this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658330/Data-grid-using-Knockout-JS-with-paging-and-sortin)

Answer (score 0):

Other useful advice. When setting the array to the ObservableArray, clear the ObservabelArray first. Instead of this:

```
self.CompanyList = ko.observableArray(ServerData);
```

Try something like this:

```
self.CompanyList = ko.observableArray();
var aux = CompanyList();
aux.length = 0;
CompanyList(ServerData);
```

I haven't try this method when declaring the variable and setting it right away, but I've use it several times working with large arrays and it's by far the fastest way to do it.